# Retornar número de linhas ou colunas de uma matriz

Tags: delphi, matriz, pascal, delphi-xe8

Tenho uma matriz como esta em Delphi XE8: `Matriz[2][3]`.

Gostaria de saber qual método posso usar para retornar o número de linhas ou colunas nessa matriz, minha idéia é loopar com 2 `for`'s e percorrer os elementos da matriz inserindo-os em uma tabela no `DataBase` e depois recupera-los em um report com o componente `TfrxDbDataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você percorrer um `Array Multi dimensional` é necessário fazer dois `laços de repetição`, segue um exemplo:

```
var
  Matriz: Array[0..1][0..2] of String;
  i, i1: Integer;
begin
  //Laço de repetição para percorrer as linhas, i representará a linha
  for i := 0 To High(Matriz) do
    begin
      //Laço de repetição para representar as colunas, i1 representará a coluna
      for i1 := 0 To High(Matriz[i]) do
        begin
          Matriz[i][i1]; //Aqui estará o conteúdo de cada espaço do seu Array
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Desculpa, digitei errado, vou corrigir. Os dois funcionam, mas no `Length` teria que ter um ` - 1` depois para não dar `Access Violation`.

High retorna a ultima posição, já o Length retorna o tamanho.